# how can I close NbDialogModule automatically after executing a function? (not on backdrop click)

Tags: angular, nebular

I'm using Nebular Angular UI Library. I'm trying different ways to find a way to close NbDialogModule but I couldn't get anywhere! Any one can help me here?
Here is one of the ways I've tried:

```
 constructor( private dialogService:NbDialogService, private ref:NbDialogRef<DialogNamePromptComponent>)
```

And in my class componant:

```
    close() {
    this.ref.close();
  }
```

And the error I get:

core.js:6241 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(ViewsModule)[NbDialogRef -> NbDialogRef -> NbDialogRef -> NbDialogRef]: NullInjectorError: No provider for NbDialogRef! NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(ViewsModule)[NbDialogRef -> NbDialogRef -> NbDialogRef -> NbDialogRef]: NullInjectorError: No provider for NbDialogRef!

Comment: From where are you trying to close the dialog?  From within the `DialogNamePromptComponent` or the component opening the dialog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can close the dialog using the dialog reference.  How you get the dialog reference depends on where you're trying to close the dialog from

#### From within the component being rendered in the dialog...

If you're trying to close the dialog from within the component that is rendered in the dialog (`DialogNamePromptComponent`), you can inject the dialog reference in the constructor of the component (`DialogNamePromptComponent`).  You can then use this reference to call `close()`.

```js
export class DialogNamePromptComponent {
  constructor(private dialogRef: NbDialogRef) {}

  public closeDialog(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

#### From within the component opening the dialog...

If you wanting to close the dialog from within the component opening the dialog, you will use the dialog reference return from the `open(...)` method of the dialog service.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  private dialogRef: NbDialogRef;

  constructor(private dialogService: NbDialogService) {}

  public openDialog(): void {
    // Open will return a dialog reference that we can use to close
    // the dialog from elsewhere.
    this.dialogRef = this.dialogService.open(DialogNamePromptComponent, { ... });
  }

  public closeDialog(): void {
    // We can use the dialog ref to close the dialog
    if (this.dialogRef) {
      this.dialogRef.close();
    }
  }
}
```

> https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/dialog/overview#nbdialogservice

Comment: Thanks. it actually helped.

Comment: Anytime, glad to help.